# Ruby's Time.strftime %P option doesn't work?

Tags: ruby

I'm building a rails application and have come across what seems to be strange behaviour. According to [Ruby's documentation of Time.strftime()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392), %P and %p are valid options:

```
%p - Meridian indicator (``AM''  or  ``PM'')
%P - Meridian indicator (``am''  or  ``pm'')
```

Using the rails console (Rails 3.0.3, ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]) I observe the following behaviour:

```
>> DateTime.now.strftime("%l:%M%P on %A %e %Y")
=> " 2:23pm on Tuesday  1 2011"
>> Time.now.strftime("%l:%M%P on %A %e %Y")
=> " 2:23P on Tuesday  1 2011"
>> Time.now.strftime("%l:%M%p on %A %e %Y")
=> " 2:23PM on Tuesday  1 2011"
>> 2.hours.ago.strftime("%l:%M%P on %A %e %Y")
=> "11:29P on Monday 28 2011"
```

Note how in DateTime.now.strftime, %P evaluates to the expected lowercase pm. With Time.now.strftime %P is rendered as an uppercase P.

The final example uses the ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone class, and that too renders incorrectly (2 hours ago is in the morning).

Is this the expected behaviour? Or should I file a bug somewhere, and if so, where's the best place to do so?

Comment: It has been fixed in   ruby-1.9.1-p378

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 1.9.2-p180 in irb:

```
Welcome to IRB. You are using ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]. Have fun ;)
>> Time.now.strftime('%p %P') #=> "PM pm"
>> DateTime.now.strftime('%p %P') #=> "PM pm"
```

With 1.8.7 in irb:

```
Welcome to IRB. You are using ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]. Have fun ;)
>> Time.now.strftime('%p %P') #=> "PM P"
>> DateTime.now.strftime('%p %P') #=> "PM pm"
```

[Rubydoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.8.7/frames) shows no "%P" support for 1.8.7:

```
Format meaning:

  %a - The abbreviated weekday name (``Sun'')
  %A - The  full  weekday  name (``Sunday'')
  %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
  %B - The  full  month  name (``January'')
  %c - The preferred local date and time representation
  %d - Day of the month (01..31)
  %H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)
  %I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)
  %j - Day of the year (001..366)
  %m - Month of the year (01..12)
  %M - Minute of the hour (00..59)
  %p - Meridian indicator (``AM''  or  ``PM'')
  %S - Second of the minute (00..60)
  %U - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Sunday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %W - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Monday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)
  %x - Preferred representation for the date alone, no time
  %X - Preferred representation for the time alone, no date
  %y - Year without a century (00..99)
  %Y - Year with century
  %Z - Time zone name
  %% - Literal ``%'' character

   t = Time.now
   t.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y")   #=> "Printed on 04/09/2003"
   t.strftime("at %I:%M%p")            #=> "at 08:56AM"
```

ActiveSupport's `ri` doc says:

```
ri ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#strftime
----------------------------------- ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#strftime
     strftime(format)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Replaces +%Z+ and +%z+ directives with +zone+ and
     +formatted_offset+, respectively, before passing to Time#strftime,
     so that zone information is correct
```

Comment: Cheers, should have checked that! Thank you :)

Comment: @Nick, you could use `sub` after your Time.strftime to force the desired case: `Time.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S %p').sub(/(AM|PM)/) { |m| m.downcase } #=> "19:04:52 pm"`